# Deserialize JSON Array with different POJOs in java with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

How can I deserialize this JSON structure ?

```
[
  {
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": "50"
  },
  [
    {
      "id": "IC.BUS.EASE.XQ",
      "name": "ion"
    },
    {
      "id": "OIUPOIUPOIU",
      "name": "lal alalalal"
    }
  ]
]
```

( I get this back from the WorldBank Api, it is a bit simplified, the exact response you find [here](http://api.worldbank.org/en/indicators?format=json&per_page=3&page=1) ).

The problem is, that i get an array of objects, where the first element is a POJO and the second element is an array of POJOs of a specific type.

The only way that I found out  to deserialize this is to be very generic which results in Lists and Maps.

```
List<Object> indicators = mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<Object>>() {});
```

Is there a better way to deserialize this JSON to get an Array or a List, where the first element is of the Object "A" and the second a List of Objects "B" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would do something like this. It's not possible to represent your data in a good way in one list on java without using a common base class. In your case this unfortunately is `Object`. You can help a bit by manipulating the response list though.

```
    ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) mapper.readTree(this.getScrape().getScrapetext());

    A a = mapper.readValue(arrayNode.get(0), A.class);

    arrayNode.remove(0);

    List<B> b = mapper.readValue(arrayNode.toString(), new TypeReference<List<B>>()
    {
    });
```

Comment: @Oskar_Kjellin: Thanks, this solved my problem. Please correct just 2 things in your answer: 1.) List<B> b = mapper.readValue(arrayNode.**get(0)**.toString() works correct. 2.) i changed this.getScrape()... to "jsonString" in the original question for understandability's sake, could you please change it in the answer as well ? Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the structure is rather irregular, in that there is no Java class definition that structurally matches a JSON Array with magic type definitions for elements by index, you probably need to do 2-pass binding.

First, you bind JSON into either `List` (or just `Object`) or `JsonNode`.
And from that, you can use `ObjectMapper.convertValue()` to extract and convert elements into actual types you want. Something like:

```
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(jsonSource);
HeaderInfo header = mapper.convertValue(jsonSource.get(0), 
   HeaderInfo.class);
IdNamePair[] stuff = mapper.convertValue(jsonSource.get(1),
   IdNamePair[].class);
```

would let you get typed values from original JSON Array.